# Why resource naming convention was changed in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, naming-conventions, multilingual

In past when building multi language apps in Android I used to place strings.xml in following tree:

```
res
├── values
│   └── strings.xml
└── values-es
    └── strings.xml
```

Currently (according to [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#CreateDirs)) it should rather look like this:

```
res
├── values
│   └── strings.xml
└── values-b+es
    └── strings.xml
```

Please note **values-b+es** instead of **values-es**. I couldn't find why it was changed and to me it looks worse than previously, so I wonder what is the reason of such change?

What's more freshly updated Android Studio still auto-generates those names in old way:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I couldn't find why it was changed

The old approach still works and is what most developers use, because that is the one that has [decent documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources). Also, the new approach only works on certain API levels (due to the poor documentation, I forget when it was added).

> I wonder what is the reason of such change?

AFAIK, the new approach employs a different naming scheme, which extends support to more language/region combinations.

Comment: Thanks for answer although I don't really see how adding hardcoded "-b" and swapping "-" to "+" could increase number of language/region combinations. If there would be alternative additions like "-c", "-d" and etc. then I would understand but currently it doesn't make any sense to me. Anyway I will accept your answer if nobody will post anything more convincing.

Comment: @LLL: No, I mean they switched systems. The old approach accepts ISO 639-1 codes; the `-b+` system I think also uses a newer standard (BCP 47, maybe?).